# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=x^{(n-\frac{x}{n})}$ on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have prove the pointwise convergence  in $(0,1)$ to the null function. For the uniformly convergence I can calculate the derivative $f'_n(x)$?

If I prove $f_n$ uniformly converge, $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx=\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} f_n(x) dx$?

$\forall n, \forall x \in (0,1) , x^{(n-\frac{x}{n})}>x^n$ so can I say Sup $x^{(n-\frac{x}{n})}$>Sup $x^n=1$ so there isn't uniformly convergence in (0,1)?

Comment: Is that exponent $\;n-\frac xn\;$ or is it $\;\frac{n-x}n\;$ ?

Answer (score 0):

For any $\;x\in (0,1)\;$ we have

$$x^{n-\frac xn}=\frac{x^n}{\left(x^{1/n}\right)^x}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac0{1}=0$$

Comment: Your first equality sign does not hold.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter True, thanks. Editing.

Comment: @DonAntonio and what do you want to show with it concerning uniform convergence?

Comment: @Gono So far, nothing: you already did something (didn't check, just read). What do you want to do concerning pointwise convergence to zero?

Comment: Should I do something? The OP already stated 

"I have prove the pointwise convergence in (0,1) to the null function."
So nothing to be done…

Answer (score 0):

Take $$x_n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \in (0,1)$$

Then $$f_n(x_n) \to \frac{1}{e}$$ hence $$||f_n||_\infty \ge f_n(x_n) \to \frac{1}{e}$$so the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: If there isn't uniformly convergence  can I calculate  two limits?

Comment: two limits for what? A limit is always unique… so I don't get what you mean.

Comment: The two limits in the initial question

Comment: OFC you can calculate both limits… both are $0$. For the RHS you already had $$\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} f_n(x) dx = \int_0^1 0 dx = 0$$
For the LHS consider that hold
$$0 \le \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx \le \int_0^1 x^{n - \frac{1}{n}} dx = \frac{n}{n^2 + n - 1}$$
Taking limits leads to $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx = 0$$

So LHS and RHS are both $0$ hence equal.